# Elastic Search Not Finding Data Directory

Tags: elasticsearch

Standing up a new cluster on ES 2.1 and I'm having trouble setting the path.data directory.

Here is my config setting

```
# ----------------------------------- Paths ------------------------------------
#
# Path to directory where to store the data (separate multiple locations by comma):
#
path.data: /home/elasticUser/elasticFiles
```

Here is the read write stuff:

```
[elasticUser@WLIELASTICP01 ~]$ ls -hn
total 0
drwxrwxrwx. 2 1002 1002 6 Dec  9 13:21 elasticFiles
drwxrwxrwx. 2 1002 1002 6 Dec  9 13:49 elasticLogs
```

I have chowned the dir to elasticUser as well.

When I fire up ES:

```
sudo systemctl start elasticsearch
```

Nothing Happens and the logs state:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to access 'path.data' (/home/elasticUser/elasticFiles)
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Security.addPath(Security.java:229)
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Security.addFilePermissions(Security.java:203)
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Security.createPermissions(Security.java:184)
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Security.configure(Security.java:105)
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.setupSecurity(Bootstrap.java:196)
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.setup(Bootstrap.java:167)
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:285)
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:35)
Caused by: java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: /home/elasticUser/elasticFiles
        at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:84)
        at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:102)
        at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:107)
        at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.createDirectory(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:384)
        at java.nio.file.Files.createDirectory(Files.java:674)
        at java.nio.file.Files.createAndCheckIsDirectory(Files.java:781)
        at java.nio.file.Files.createDirectories(Files.java:767)
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Security.ensureDirectoryExists(Security.java:250)
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Security.addPath(Security.java:227)
        ... 7 more
```

I had the same issues with data.logs and just changed them back to default.. any ideas?

Comment: If you chown'ed the folder, why do we see `1002` and the owner and group and not `elasticUser`? Can you show the `chown` command you've used?

Answer (score 0):

Figured this out...

Since my "OPS" team mounted the data drive on /home/ I needed to grant access to /home/elasticUser/ .